# how to know the name of the jar that's running

Tags: java, jar, filepath

I need to create a batch file that run my java jar at windows startup.
To do so i need to know the name of the jar that i want to autorun.
I assume that the user can change the name of the jar, so before the creation of the bat i want to check if the name of my jar is changed.

i can get the absolute position of the jar with this code, but how i can get it's name?

```
    File f = new File(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
    File dir = f.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile();
    String path = dir.toString();
```

thanks.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense. If the user change the name of the jar, there's no need to "find" the jar in your batch file. Just point it to the place you already know. It's the same thing of looking for this jar for the case the user move it for another folder.

Comment: everytime that the jar run with the option "start at windows startup" as marked it will regenerate the bat file with current position and name.

Comment: If you check the docs here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html
you'll find that the system property java.class.path may contain more than just the one directory that you want. The class path can have a lot of entries in it, and then you'd be left sorting those. Evgeniy Dofofeev's answer, querying the class for its location seems to me to be a stronger method of finding the location of your jar file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the way is to get the URL of a class code source, eg

```
    URL r = JdbcTemplate.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
    System.out.println(r);
```

prints

```
file:/D:/.repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
```

in my project